# "Out of something or someone"/ "short on something or someone"

Tags: word-usage

I needed 10 watches but I realised that I had only 9. So what should be used:

> 1.) I am out one watch.
>
> 2.) I am one watch out.
>
> 3.) I am one watch short.
>
> 4.) I am short on one watch.

And if we're talking about a person:

> 1.) We're one player short.
>
> 2.) We're short on one player.
>
> 3.) We're out one player.
>
> 4.) We're one player out.

So what sounds natural #1,#2,#3 or #4 in both the contexts?

Answer (score 1):

> I am out one watch.

This doesn't fit your situation; I might use this if someone got into my gym locker and stole my watch.

> I am one watch short.
>   I am short one watch.

Both of these work for the situation you describe (notice that I removed the "on" from #4).

Your #2 sounds more awkward than idiomatic.

---

Likewise, if we needed nine players for a baseball team, and we only had eight, we could say either one of these:

> We're one player short.
>   We're short one player.

However, the phrase:

> We're out one player

would make more sense if a player was on the team but then couldn't play for some reason (perhaps due to injury, or a red card).